# How to change boolean value at a certain index of a boolean list

Tags: python

I have a boolean list (S) of length n (user input) containing all True values (index 0 and 1 are set to False). If index k % 2 == 0 or k % 3 == 0, I need to change the boolean value at k to False. The code I have is:

```
if (k % 2 == 0 or k % 3 == 0):
   S[k] = False
```

However, the Boolean values stay True at all k indexes where the if statement applies to. I feel like its a syntax problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: How are you incrementing `k`? Your code should work as expected. I have a feeling this `if` statement is not the root of the problem.

Comment: Can you provide your `boolean` list?

Comment: @gmdev Yes you're right, the problem with my code wasn't the if statement actually, it was the while loop before it, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

works on this example

```
a = [True]*5
print(a)
for k, x in enumerate(a):
    if (k % 2 == 0 or k % 3 == 0):
        a[k] = False
print(a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[True, True, True, True, True]
[False, True, False, False, False]
```

You definitely use illegal `k` index

Comment: `a = [True]*5` may be a cleaner way to initialize the list instead of a list comp in this case.

Comment: Agreed, i just add one example

Answer (score 0):

```
length = len(S)
for k in range(length):
   if (k % 2 == 0 or k % 3 == 0):
       S[k] = False
```